# Fluent UI combobox Label

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

For controls like [fluent-text-input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/components/text-field?pivots=typescript) we can add a label which appears just above the control. This seems to be not possible for  [fluent-combobox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/components/combobox?pivots=typescript)

Any one has suggestions on how to add label for the combo box just like the text box?